# Limiting the resultset size on a google spreadsheets/forms list feed

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I want to use the list based query interface to google spreadsheets/forms but want to make sure that the number of rows I get back is limited to a specified maximum.  Is there a way of doing this?

Thanks.

Tom.

Comment: The cell feed class has a `setMaxRow()` function. I had the same problem you are facing and ended up using the cell feednsince I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Sure... you can do it on a cell feed, but I don't see a way of doing it on a list feed.

Answer (score 4):

There's a query parameter `max-results` that can limit number of rows returned by a list feed.

```
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/key/worksheetId/private/full?max-results=10
```

It is not supported in all client libraries though.

Comment: Nice one.... thanks.  This is exactly what I was hoping for.  I don't see it in the docs.

Comment: Great answer. I can confirm it's working with the new Google Sheets. What's your source for this information?